# Audio play with prgressbar in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this code i want to display progress based on how much percent the audio is played.

index.html

```
 <i class="btn btn-warning fa fa-play-circle" ng-if="chat.isPlaying==false" ng-click="playFile(chat.msg,chat.isPlaying,$index,'playfile'+$index)"></i>
<progressbar value="currentTime"></progressbar>
                            <audio id="playfile{{$index}}"></audio>
```

Comment: Easy. You have audio duration, current time from AudioAPI. You just need to calculate percent. The best thing would be to write a directive for this.

Comment: but i am getting audio.duration is NaN

Answer (score 0):

didn't test it but I think something like this could workout:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
   var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
   var value = 0;
   if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
      value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
   }
   progress.value = value;
}, false);
```

Comment: but i am getting audio.duration is NaN

Comment: its seems like you have preload="none" attribute on your audio tag so you either need to remove that and let it preload or look it the audio.duration when the user actually start playing the audio